# What is Romanticism? Does one still believe in such a conception? Seemingly opposed to rational Truth!

Tags: ontology

This is a dramatically-inflected, or modulated, if you like, word about the context of the inquiry:

The peevishness of the higher-caliber professors, in the elite American universities, when confronted with the possibility of being imputed with Romanticism, is symptomatic of the failure to resolve the American formula for the division of human possibilities. Now found in the anti-intellectual notion of the ‘spiritual’, as opposed to the so-called finite secular sphere of social construction. “Finite” then points us to the distinctive and peculiar notion of the empirical found in the same circles. One who surveyed this, from a high peak, might be struck by awe. Much in the way the one with a Weltanschauung, in the age of Burckhardt, and Wagner, felt the radiance of High German myths, performed on the stages of Bayreuth.

Romanticism seems to signal some kind of flight from the “finite”. The concept of the forest, of the wanderer, of the special way, of the flight from scientific rationality into the fairytale world. However, doesn’t one who survives all this, see only a specific set of biases, of inherited ideological dispositions? Doesn't one suspect that consciousness itself is infinite, unintellectually-religious, foolish, non-rational. The only place from which rationality can be defined, the seat of arbitrariness?

Those primitive disputatious rascals who see such forms appearing before them, of the American world as such, might, heart and spirit, stream into the dissenting polemics of academic print. However, in the decisive respect, these would be only those who had failed to grasp the golden nugget of their own perspicacity. Had failed to understand the error of epochs. Of standpoints as such. Had let oneself bathe in the light cast by the transformations of worlds, but not confronted the burden of that vision of the transformations in and of oneself. Once not seen, now evident injunctions from unknown quarters.

I wonder if one must comprehend this question form American and European and Russian, and Chinese angles? And not just suddenly in a great unitray thought.

Comment: i blame s'adorno

Comment: I am sensing a lot of angst towards both American academic philosophers and romantics. But what is the question? Are there still philosophers with romantic leanings and qualms with "rational truth"? Avez vous lu [Meillassoux et Harman](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/lic3.12254/abstract)?

Comment: [Romanticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanticism) "was an artistic, literary, musical and intellectual movement that originated in Europe toward the end of the 18th century". Thus, an historical fact more than an "ontological" category.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question whether one still believes in such a conception. It can't be limited to "historical fact". Since, as what is written says, it is closer to the questions Plato asked. I.e., something about which one is still asking what it means. Something that plays an outstanding role in the great centers of thought.  Appeals to encyclopedias don't work in such cases. As if one could get the definitive answer tot he question What is Justice, or does one still believe in Justice, in such a fashion.

Comment: Addendum: I would ask one to re-read the question, now being somewhat better informed as to its purport.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that early German Romanticism originated from a response to Fichte, through Fichte's interpretation of Kant - a response to the idea that we "know a priori only what we create" (Section 3, Chapter 8 in The Romantic Imperative by Frederick Beiser https://books.google.com.au/books?id=b2iWCwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

So Romanticism centred around the idea of sublimating the subject in objective reality, as a way of overcoming man's alienation from reality through idealism

Comment: I thank you for this answer. Though, it is perhaps somewhat too antiquarian in character. Since the issue is playing an active role in the deliberation in the key centers of intelligence on the earth, not yesterday, but now.